# Removing files that don't end with -out

Tags: delete

How would I delete all files in a directory and its subdirectories that do not end with -out? For instance delete `foo.bar` but do not delete `foo-out.bar`.

EDIT:

I have tried

```
for a_file in $(find .  ! -name '*-out*'); do rm  $a_file; done;
```

But this script doesn't incorporate spaces. How would I fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using the `find` command's built-in `-delete` action? that should be whitespace safe

```
find . ! -name '*-out*' -type f -delete
```

Otherwise, you could do a null-terminated while loop - make sure you quote the filename variable as well

```
while read -rd $'\0' f; do rm "$f"; done < <(find . ! -name '*-out*' -type f -print0)
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer.

You don't have to use a for loop. `find` provides `-exec` and `-delete`.

A quick test

```
cd `mktemp -d`
touch {1..9}\ -out{a..c}
$ find . -name '*-out*'
./2 -outb
./8 -outb
./9 -outa
./4 -outc
./6 -outb
./5 -outc
./7 -outb
./9 -outb
./2 -outa
./4 -outa
./8 -outc
./8 -outa
./7 -outc
./3 -outb
./6 -outa
./3 -outa
./1 -outb
./9 -outc
./1 -outa
./5 -outa
./4 -outb
./3 -outc
./1 -outc
./5 -outb
./2 -outc
./7 -outa
./6 -outc
```

It works with spaces.

What you need is:

`find . ! -name '*-out*' -exec rm -f {} \;`

A safer alternative: `find . -name '*-out*' -exec rm -i {} \;`

**NOTE**: use `-exec rm -i {} \;` to confirm deletion.